# How to migrate old Mongoose Schema data to new Mongoose Schema Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My previous Mongoose Schema is

```js
    social:{
    instagram: String,
    facebook: String,
    whatsapp: String,
    }
```

and my new Mongoose Schema is

```js
    social:{
    instagram: {
    data: String,
            active: {
              type: Boolean,
              default: true
            }
    },
    facebook:{
    data: String,
            active: {
              type: Boolean,
              default: true
            }
    },
    whatsapp:{
    data: String,
            active: {
              type: Boolean,
              default: true
            }
    }
    }
```

so basically in previous model I am storing link directly in variable like instagram,facebook,whatsapp

but in new model , I am storing link in data variable under main variable and adding addtional active variable , so how can I move previous around 20 data in new format of schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one `update` query that will transfer all documents to new structure. You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "social.instagram.active": {
    "$exists": false
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "social": {
        "instagram": {
          "data": "$social.instagram",
          "active": true
        },
        "facebook": {
          "data": "$social.facebook",
          "active": true
        },
        "whatsapp": {
          "data": "$social.whatsapp",
          "active": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tKYTsmnXdIB)

Comment: How to not update new schema data ? like we can use $exist for that?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `$exists`. I updated my answer and working example. Can you check it again?